# perl find and replace ../ and &#160;

Tags: perl

I am using Perl to replace all instances of

`../../../../../../abc'` and `&#160;`

in a string with

`/` and `&nbsp;`, respectively.

The method I am using looks like this:

```
sub encode
{
    my $result = $_[0];
    $result =~ s/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\/..\//\//g;
    $result =~ s/&#160;/&nbsp;/g;
    return $result;
}
```

Is this correct?

Comment: What do your test cases tell you about its correctness? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It will print `/foo&nbsp;bar/baz`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $result = "../../../../../../foo&#160;bar/baz";

#$result =~ s/(\.\.\/)+/\//g; #for any number of ../
$result =~ s/(\.\.\/){6}/\//g; #for 6 exactly

$result =~ s/&#160;/&nbsp;/g;
print $result . "\n";
```

Comment: how about if i want to specify that there are 6 groups of '../' ?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, yes, although the first regex has to be written in a different way: because `.` matches any character, we have to escape it `\.` or put it in its own character class `[.]`. The first regex can also be written cleaner as

```
...;
$result =~ s{  (?: [.][.]/ ){6}  }
            {/}gx;
...;
```

We look for the literal pattern `../` repeated `6` times and then replace it. Because I use curly braces as a delimiter I don't have to escape the slash. Because I use the `/x` modifier I can have these spaces inside the regex improving readability.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot the abc, i think:

```
sub encode
{
    my $result = $_[0];
    $result =~ s/(?:..\/){6}abc/\//g;
    $result =~ s/&#160;/&nbsp;/g;
    return $result;
}
```